# Conflicting types error in compiler

Tags: c

My issue is that I keep getting the same type of error and I can not understand why. I'm fairly sure I declared and defined it before the main function.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void functn (int x);

int functn(int x, int result){
    result = (x-1)+2;
    if (x <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return result;
    }
}

int main (){

int x, y;
  printf ("Enter the value of x: ");
  scanf ("%d", &x);
  y = f(x);
  printf ("%d", y);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `functn()` function definition and declaration are different

Comment: `void functn (int x);` and `int functn(int x, int result)`, Yep, I'd say the compiler was right!

Comment: Just delete the function declaration at the top. The definition occurs before the function is called so it's not needed.

Comment: It still won't compile

Comment: Also you are calling function `f()` which is not shown in your code

Comment: Maybe the function name is a typo. In that case your function takes two parameter while you are calling it with one

Comment: try [this](http://ideone.com/S1ipcw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems in `functn`. Primarily passing `result`. When you pass result to `functn`, `functn` receives a **copy** of `result` and the only way to get the modified value is to **return** the modified value. You can also pass a pointer to `result` and update `*result` in `functn` (similar to what you do now), that would eliminate the need to return a value, as any changes to `result` would be visible back in the calling function (`main()` here). Further, there is no need for *global variables*. Simply declare the variables local to `main` and pass as parameters, as required.

The following example declares `functn` (simply `f` below) to do **both**, take a pointer to `result` (e.g. `&result`) as a parameter, while also returning `result`, which allows you to either assign the return or not, but always have the updated value for `result` back in `main`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f (int x, int *result);

int main (void){

    int x, y, result = 0;
    printf ("Enter the value of x: ");
    if (scanf ("%d", &x) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error scanf, invalid conversion.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    y = f (x, &result);
    printf ("y = f(%d) => %d\n", x, y);

    return 0;
}

int f (int x, int *result) 
{
    *result = (x-1)+2;

    if (x <= 0)
        return 0;

    return *result;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/yfx
Enter the value of x: 5
y = f(5) => 6
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Return type of `functn()` different in declaration and definition. So, use

```
int functn(int x);
```

instead of

```
int functn(int x, int result)
```

Remove `int result` from function argument and declare inside function. like,

```
int functn(int x)
{
    int result = 0;
    result = (x-1)+2;
    if (x <= 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        return result;
    }
}
```

Also, correct function call, like

```
y = functn(x);
```

instead of

```
 y = f(x);
```